# Conflict between mouseenter event and absolute position of the elements

Tags: css, jquery, mouseenter, jquery-hover

i have a div containing multiple divs with absolute position, i want to handle the mouse enter event for the parent div i use this fiddle:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JP6aV/30/)
it doesnt works correctly is their any other way to handle this problem ?

**HTML Markup**

```
<div id="content">
SYDNEY (Reuters) - An Australian man had his driving licence suspended for 10 months and was fined after he was
 <div class="abs"></div>
caught driving a scooter made of a motorised beer cooler capable of carrying several dozen drinks -- after knocking back a few.
</div>
<div id="output">   
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function() {
var output = $("#output");
$("#content")
  .mouseenter(function(e){
    output.text("I'm in!");
}).mouseout(function(e) {
    output.text("I'm out!"); 
});
});​


#content {
background-color:#cccc99;   
position:relative;     
}
.abs{
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 left:70px;
 background-color:red; 
 width:30px;
 height:30px;   
 }​
```

Comment: It looks normal, where is problem??

Comment: I think question should be Closed in that case? :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're halfway there yourself. Because the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events bubble, they will trigger multiple times as you `mouseover` and `mouseout` of child elements of the element your event handlers are watching. jQuery provides the IE-inspired `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, which only trigger for mouse events on the watched elements themselves, and are not triggered for events on the element's children. Use the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events, and your code will work as expected. See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JP6aV/31/). Alternatively, use the jQuery [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) syntax, which internally uses the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, wrapped in a convenient syntax.

Comment: It looks like it's working as I would expect :-p Each event handler fires in turn, spitting out the output based on the last watched element that the mouse entered or left. So if you mouse over the red box, then leave through the top, the `mouseleave` for the red box fires, then the `mouseleave` for its parent container fires (the mouse events are handled in an in-to-out order). Did you need it to work differently?

Comment: That works, but only if the absolute div is added as a child of the tested div. If added for example at the root of the document, we would get a mouseleave event.

Comment: Yes, the events "bubble" upwards through the DOM to the parent elements. Most events behave this way… For example, when you click an `A` tag the `click` event first happens on the `A` tag, then the `A` tag's parent element, then up and up the DOM the event travels. Only when the event reaches the document root does the browser navigate to the new page as specified by the `A` tag. You can actually attach a `click` event handler anywhere above the `A` tag and see the event (and even stop it from bubbling up further). See http://jsfiddle.net/qhtEn/

Answer (score 2):

As I understand - problem with red div. And that is correct. Use [jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead of mouseenter/mouseout

```
$(function() {
    var output = $("#output");
    $("#content")
      .hover(function(e){
        output.text("I'm in!");
    },function(e) {
        output.text("I'm out!"); 
    });
});​
```